# Subrings of the reals given by irrational numbers

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, real-numbers

What are the (non-unital) subrings of $\mathbb{R}$ that meet $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\{0\}$? Is there any of countable index as abelian subgroup?

Comment: What did you mean by "meet $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\{0\}$"?

Comment: That $H$ is a subring such that $H \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{0\}$

Comment: Also, does non-unital mean it does not have a unit (multiplicative identity)?

Comment: That's right. Since the intersection with $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial, in particular does not contain $1$. That's why it is in bracket, it is actually redundant.

Comment: Every subring arises as an image of some polynomial ring (potentially with infinitely many variables) over $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular any subring generated by a single irrational will be an example. I don't know the answer to the second question though.